# How to fix 'NoneType' object is not callable while returning wrapper function?

Tags: python, decorator

```
def func_needs_decorator():
    print("I wanna a decorator urgently")
    


def new_decorator(original_funct):
    
    def wrapper_funct():
        print("Some extra code before the original function")
        original_funct()
        print("Some extra code after the original funciton")
    return wrapper_funct()     

func_needs_decorator = new_decorator(func_needs_decorator)
print(func_needs_decorator())

>>>'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I couldn't understand why I'm getting that error.Why am I getting that error?How can i fix it?Can you tell me the procces of this code?How does it work?

Comment: you must return a function, not it's result. so `wrapper_funct` is a reference to the method, i.e. it points to the first byte in memory of the first instruction. `wrapper_funct()` calls it and returns back whatever it has computed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `wrapper_funct` and returning its return value instead of returning `wrapper_funct` itself.

```
return wrapper_funct()
```

should be

```
return wrapper_funct
```